# cannot add entity to out-of-the-box jhipster project

Tags: rest, cassandra, jhipster

I built a jhipster site with react. So far nothing has been altered except I created an entity in JHipster Studio and installed that via `jhipster import-jdl {pathToDownloaded.jh}`. Everything installed without errors. I have not altered the auto-generated code for the controllers or anything. Here is the contents of the .jh file that was downloaded from JHiptser Studio

```
entity MyFile {
    identifier Long unique
    title String required
    url String
    path String required
    mimeType String required
    fileSize Long
    source String
    file Blob required
}
```

I did the command to migrate cassandra, and run the build and start the servers. The page loads and I'm able to log in using admin credentials. However, when I navigate to the entity list, create a new entity, fill out the required fields and hit save, I get a 500 error.

I used the console in chrome and see the following errors.
[image]

When I click on the link on the top error it takes me to the following message

```
{
  "type" : "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title" : "Unauthorized",
  "status" : 401,
  "detail" : "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
  "path" : "/api/my-files",
  "message" : "error.http.401"
}
```

but this error doesn't make sense, I've logged in with the default admin credentials. Is there some setup I'm missing to allow entity creation?

Additional steps I've taken to debug have been to try and use Postman to make the API calls. I used the admin login to get a token and assigned that as a bearer credential to make the calls, which seems to get rid of the 401. It does successfully return an empty list on GET, but POST does not work, I get a variety of different errors ranging from invalid type errors to undefined column name errors, depending on what json data I'm trying to send it.

edit: stacktrace from the local console that runs the gradlew

```
2020-08-14 11:19:03.134 ERROR 20672 --- [ XNIO-1 task-36] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Internal Server Error

        org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraTypeMismatchException: SessionCallback; CQL [INSERT INTO myfile (file,file_content_type,filesize,id,identifier,mimetype,path,source,title,url) VALUES (?,?,null,?,null,?,?,?,?,?);]; Value 0 of type class [B does not correspond to any CQL3 type; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Value 0 of type class [B does not correspond to any CQL3 type
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translate(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:97)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraAccessor.translate(CassandraAccessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.translateException(CqlTemplate.java:732)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.execute(CqlTemplate.java:134)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.executeSave(CassandraTemplate.java:860)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.executeSave(CassandraTemplate.java:851)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:666)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:649)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:634)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.SimpleCassandraRepository.save(SimpleCassandraRepository.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor108.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy180.save(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor107.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy180.save(Unknown Source)
        at com.project.site.web.rest.myfileResource.createmyfile(myfileResource.java:57)
        at com.project.site.web.rest.myfileResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$77234b15.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
        at com.project.site.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:103)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor73.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691)
        at com.project.site.web.rest.myfileResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c93d9ae7.createmyfile(<generated>)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:113)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at com.project.site.web.filter.RouteDetectorFilter.doFilter(RouteDetectorFilter.java:91)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at com.project.site.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:40)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SessionRestoringHandler.handleRequest(SessionRestoringHandler.java:119)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376)
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Value 0 of type class [B does not correspond to any CQL3 type
        at com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Utils.convert(Utils.java:354)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.BuiltStatement.getValues(BuiltStatement.java:268)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.makeRequestMessage(SessionManager.java:600)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.SessionManager.executeAsync(SessionManager.java:142)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:58)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate$StatementCallback.doInSession(CassandraTemplate.java:974)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate$StatementCallback.doInSession(CassandraTemplate.java:964)
        at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.execute(CqlTemplate.java:132)
        ... 162 common frames omitted
        Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [ANY <-> [B]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.notFound(CodecRegistry.java:806)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.createCodec(CodecRegistry.java:649)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.findCodec(CodecRegistry.java:631)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.codecFor(CodecRegistry.java:476)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Utils.convert(Utils.java:348)
        ... 169 common frames omitted

        2020-08-14 11:19:03.144  WARN 20672 --- [ XNIO-1 task-36] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraTypeMismatchException: SessionCallback; CQL [INSERT INTO myfile (file,file_content_type,filesize,id,identifier,mimetype,path,source,title,url) VALUES (?,?,null,?,null,?,?,?,?,?);]; Value 0 of type class [B does not correspond to any CQL3 type; nested exception is com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidTypeException: Value 0 of type class [B does not correspond to any CQL3 type]
```

Comment: @GaëlMarziou I edited my question to add the stacktrace.

Comment: So,  it's Cassandra complaining about "Value 0 of type class [B does not correspond to any CQL3 type". I don't know anything about Cassandra support in JHipster (not the most popular option in JHipster) but as your problem seems to be easily reproducible, I recommend that you open an issue on https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues with details from "jhipster info" output